# How to properly rotate and realod UITableView when it's in enter-search-text mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, rotation, reload

I'm implementing UITableViewController that displays one cell in portrait mode, and two cells in landscape mode. I'm successfully reusing cells with indetifiers. Also, I have a flag for checking odd number of records and displaying correct number of records (omitting right cell in landscape mode). Also, I'm using a search field.

Now, I have everything working: the table correctly rotates, search correctly filters the records. The problem appears on the situations related with enter-search-text + rotate, for example: I'm launching the app, the table fills with records. Then, I'm entering some text in search field, then filtering records and reloading tableview in "textDidChange". The table successfully filters 3 records. Now, I'm rotating to landscape mode while in enter-search-text mode. But now, the table displays only 2 records.

All the problems start when I'm starting to rotate while in enter-search-text mode. The table misses some records, misses some right cells in landscape mode. I don't know why it behaves because I'm calling "[self.tableView reloadData]" both in "textDidChange" and "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" methods. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution in this ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555969/uitableview-reloaddata-issue/2556971#comment-8978636)). It appears that there are two different tableViews for displaying rows in table: one for self.tableView in default mode and another one for  "self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView" (if you are using a search controller). So, I have fixed my problem with this code:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{

  if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]){
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
  } else{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using different .xib files? Also it's a bad way to write code in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` use `didRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` instead.

Comment: Nop, I'm using only one nib file. I moved reload table call from shouldaAutorotate to didRotate but that didn't solved the problem :(

Comment: @Eugene Isn't your 2nd method named: `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`? The one you suggest using is: `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`.